# Lravel 5.6 : emails sent using mail facade go to junk for only hotmail and outlook addresses

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, outlook, html-email, hotmail

i'm setting up automatic emails for events like user registration and change password etc. the problem is that the emails go to junk for Hotmail,outlook whereas work fine for gmail.

I have tested my email for junk content and https://www.mail-tester.com/ gave me a score of 8.5/10 and i don't want to ask my recipients to manually add me to safe senders list

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your server and sender for it appear in inbox. Have a look at SPF and DKIM.
https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/understanding-spf-and-dkim/

You can also use other email services such as mailchimp, amazon ses etc

Comment: hi, i have verified my SPF and DKIM and also checked for DMARC validation . i'm using mailgun with mail facade